# Bootstrap: why my pb pt py or mr mt mx don't work in bootstrap columns and also sm sx dosent work.?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Here is the complete code of the file. The Pb is not working and also the other padding and margin attributes. I had to do CSS for this. But I want to do it with bootstrap. sm sx md also not working. Anyone know any solution?

I just wanna know why bootstrap attributes are not working. why I need to use CSS for this.

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
            <style>
              #header{
                background: url(images/grass.jpg) center center/cover no-repeat;
              }
    ** this for the cards that are in the form to show images.
              .card-img-top {
            width: 100%;
            height: 15vw;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
                 </style>
        
            <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
            <title>Pattern</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <h1 align="center">Pattern</h1>
        
           <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark">
            <div class="container">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-binoculars-fill mr-3 mb-2" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M4.5 1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3 2.5V3h4v-.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5.5 1h-1zM7 4v1h2V4h4v.882a.5.5 0 0 0 .276.447l.895.447A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 15 7.118V13H9v-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .146-.354l.854-.853V9.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.793l.854.853A.5.5 0 0 1 7 11.5V13H1V7.118a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 .83-1.342l.894-.447A.5.5 0 0 0 3 4.882V4h4zM1 14v.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 16h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 7 14.5V14H1zm8 0v.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 1.5h3a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5V14H9zm4-11H9v-.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 1h1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13 2.5V3z"/>
        </svg>PATTERN</a>
            </div>
           </nav>
        
           <section id="header" class="jumbotron text-center text-light">
           <h1 class="display-3 ">PATTERN</h1>
           <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
           </p>
           <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Do Something</a>
           <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Another thing</a>
        
           </section>
        
        
         <!--   <section id="gallery1">
             <div class="container">
               <div class="card">
                 <img class="card-img-top" src="images/sea.jpg">
                 <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">First Image</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Download</a>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-heart" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
        </svg></a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </section>
         -->
        
        
        <section id="gallery2">
           <div class="container">
            <div class="card" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
              <div class="row">
    
        // cards to show image.
        
               <div class="col-lg-`enter code here`4 pb-10">
                 <img class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item" src="images/sea.jpg">
                 <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">First Image</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Download</a>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-heart" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                     </svg></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
        
               <div class="col-lg-4" style="width: 18rem;">
                 <img class="card-img-top" src="images/beach.jpg">
                 <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">First Image</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Download</a>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-heart" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                     </svg></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
        
        
               <div class="col-lg-4" style="width: 18rem;">
                 <img class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item" src="images/gross.jpg">
                 <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">First Image</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Download</a>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-heart" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                     </svg></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div> 
        </ssection>
        
            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
            <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          </body>
        </html>`
```

Comment: Your leading `section` tag is broken und you have a typo in the closing `section`  tag. Are those present in your code as well, or are they only introduced when you wrote the answer?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Why would you rollback an edit that adds proper code highlighting and makes the post **much** easier to read? Without the highlighting, the code is  far, far worse to read.

Comment: `pb-10` is not a valid bootstrap class. You have too much code to go through to find other classes but my guess is that they were not valid either.

Comment: @Polygnome Because what it added in code highlighting, it made more difficult with extra spacing to the left. I was actually going to fix that until I realised the question is down to using classes that don't exist so it the question should probably be closed anyway so I didn;t bother.

Comment: can you send bootstrap CDN and version? which you are using?.

Comment: @KashifShahzad The problem is just they the OP is using an invalid class `pb-10` doesn't exist in *any* version of Bootstrap

Comment: yes `pb-10` is an invalid class you can give maximum `pb-5`

Comment: @KashifShahzad i tried pb-5 but not working.now, i posted the whole code.

Comment: @FluffyKitten i am now posted the whole code and the iamge of the project. i hope it will makes thing easy.

Comment: @sam_shah I post your code. check this once. `pb-5` is working fine

Answer (score 0):

**try this code. `pb-5` is working fine**

```html
<html lang="en">
          <head>
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <style>
              #header{
                background: url(images/grass.jpg) center center/cover no-repeat;
              }
    ** this for the cards that are in the form to show images.
              .card-img-top {
            width: 100%;
            height: 15vw;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
                 </style>
        
            <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
            <title>Pattern</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <h1 align="center">Pattern</h1>
        
           <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark">
            <div class="container">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-binoculars-fill mr-3 mb-2" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M4.5 1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3 2.5V3h4v-.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5.5 1h-1zM7 4v1h2V4h4v.882a.5.5 0 0 0 .276.447l.895.447A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 15 7.118V13H9v-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .146-.354l.854-.853V9.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.793l.854.853A.5.5 0 0 1 7 11.5V13H1V7.118a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 .83-1.342l.894-.447A.5.5 0 0 0 3 4.882V4h4zM1 14v.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 16h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 7 14.5V14H1zm8 0v.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 1.5h3a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5V14H9zm4-11H9v-.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 1h1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13 2.5V3z"/>
        </svg>PATTERN</a>
            </div>
           </nav>
        
           <section id="header" class="jumbotron text-center text-light">
           <h1 class="display-3 ">PATTERN</h1>
           <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
           </p>
           <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Do Something</a>
           <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Another thing</a>
        
           </section>
        
        

        
        
        <section id="gallery2">
           <div class="container">
            <div class="card" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
              <div class="row">
    
        // cards to show image.
        
               <div class="col-lg-4  pb-5">
                 <img class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item" src="images/sea.jpg">
                 <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">First Image</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Download</a>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-heart" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                     </svg></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
        
               <div class="col-lg-4" style="width: 18rem;">
                 <img class="card-img-top" src="images/beach.jpg">
                 <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">First Image</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Download</a>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-heart" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                     </svg></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
        
        
               <div class="col-lg-4" style="width: 18rem;">
                 <img class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item" src="images/gross.jpg">
                 <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">First Image</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Download</a>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-heart" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
                     </svg></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div> 
        </ssection>
        
            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
            <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a few errors in your HTML code so for starter use [this HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Also you should know that the spacing system in bootstrap consists of 5 levels. `p-1` to `p-5`  same goes for `pt`, `pl`, `pr`, and `PB` as well as margin [spacing and how it works in bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/).

You were trying to apply `pb-10` which does not exist. That's why it didn't work for you.

Also your closing tag for `section` is miss spelled.